# Screen rotation problem

Tags: screen

I have a new iPad (iOS 11.3) and the control center does not contain anything related to screen orientation or lock rotation. I tried to ask Siri about this and got gibberish. Does anyone have a suggestion? I am starting to think it just might not be an option with the new iPad though that seems crazy.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) It's a little unclear to me what you're actually asking here? Are you saying that your screen doesn't rotate? Or that you can't lock rotation? Or that you just don't seem to have the *option* to lock/unlock rotation?

Comment: You can turn off screen rotation from the control center, swipe up from the bottom of the screen and look for a padlock icon with an arrow around it. Also if you use the zoomed interface that will prevent rotation outside of apps.

Answer (score 1):

Side key button which is used for Mute/Unmute in iPhone. That key is used in iPad for orientation Lock/Unlock. Try it once.